# Accessing common objects without prefixing

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have an app I wrote quite a while ago.  It is a database app, with a lot of Ttable and TSQL components, placed on the Main Form (so it is quite messy).  I am updating the app, and I want to use a datamodule. If I do that, I will have to change all of my code from Table.fieldbyName to Datmodule.FieldByName.  I will have to do this type thing with a lot of different components, in a lot of different calls, (Table.Edit, Table.Post, etc) My question is... Is there a way to tell the compiler, if you don't find the object in the current form, look for it in TDatamodule?  I realize I can use the 'With DataModule do' syntax, but I am hoping there is something else.  Is there something I can do with NameSpace here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way to approach this would be to rename your tTable references using a search/replace tool, such as GExperts Grep Searching.  Example: if you have a table called "tSales" that is now located in a datamodule named "Dm", you could just do a Grep Search for "tSales" for all files within the current project, and then replace with "Dm.tSales".  The result is code that is much more readable and maintainable going forward.

Comment: Can't the rename refactoring do that in a safer way? The problem with grep is that it can't understand the syntax and may rename other unrelated objects that happen to have the same name.

Comment: but it's not a simple rename refactor... if I absolutely wanted to leave most of my code the same (big "IF") then I would simply add a property named "TableName" that returned the table and use a getter to reference the datamodule

Comment: Having multiple components with the same name is another issue :)